# Prove that $ \int\limits_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{e^{2 x} (1-x)^2+e^{-2 x} (1+x)^2}\,dx=\dfrac{3\pi}{8} $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Is this conjecture true?

> Conjecture:
>   $$
> \int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{e^{2 x} (1-x)^2+e^{-2 x} (1+x)^2}\,dx=\dfrac{3\pi}{8}
> $$

I found it myself based on numerical evidence. Need help in analytical proof. Thanks.

Comment: To the person who voted to close, care to explain???

Comment: What have you tried sofar?

Comment: @Nosrati what have I tried? First I found it by numerical calculation. I'm not very strong at analytics. I don't even know where to start tbh.

Comment: Maybe you lack context on this question and that's why you got some close votes + downvotes? It is okay if you don't have any approaches, but how did this integral arrive to you? Surely you didn't dream about it. Also maybe you can include what are you studying :)

Comment: this might work: the integrant is even, so write it as an integral over the real numbers, find the zeros of the denominator, then evaluate the corresponding contour integrals.

Comment: Have you considered using Wolfram alpha? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2++%2F+(e%5E(2x)+(1+-+x)%5E2+%2B+e%5E(-2x)+(1+%2B+x)%5E2)dx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier than I exspected in the first place. However, first of all lets denote your integral as

> $$\mathfrak I~=~\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{e^{2x}(1-x)^2+e^{-2x}(1+x)^2}\mathrm d x$$

We may rewrite the integral a little bit. According to *Trebor*'s answer we have to exspect an inverse tangent with an argument of the form $z=e^{2x}\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ thus write $\mathfrak I$ as

$$\begin{align*}
\mathfrak I=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{e^{2x}(1-x)^2+e^{-2x}(1+x)^2}\mathrm d x&=\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+\left(e^{2x}\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2}\frac{x^2e^{2x}\mathrm d x}{(1+x)^2}
\end{align*}$$

Now we can try the straightforward substitution $z=e^{2x}\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ with a corresponding differential given by $dz=-2\frac{x^2e^{2x}\mathrm d x}{(1+x)^2}$ and therefore the whole integral boils down to

$$\begin{align*}
\mathfrak I &=\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+\left(e^{2x}\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2}\frac{x^2e^{2x}\mathrm d x}{(1+x)^2}\\
&=\int_1^{-\infty} \frac1{1+z^2}\frac{-\mathrm dz}{2}\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^1 \frac{\mathrm d z}{1+z^2}\\
&=\frac12\left[\arctan{z}\right]_{-\infty}^1
\end{align*}$$

> $$\therefore~\mathfrak I ~=~\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{e^{2x}(1-x)^2+e^{-2x}(1+x)^2}\mathrm d x~=~\frac{3\pi}8$$

Where we used the symmetry aswell as well-known values of the tangent function.

Answer (score 6):

Well, we can just rewrite the integral as: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{e^{2 x} (1-x)^2+e^{-2 x} (1+x)^2}\,dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{e^{2x}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2+e^{-2x}}\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx$$
$$=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{4x}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2+1}\frac{1}{e^{-2x}}\frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2}dx =\int_0^\infty \frac{\color{blue}{e^{2x}}}{\left(\color{red}{e^{2x}\cdot\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)^2+1}\color{blue}{\frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2}dx}$$ Now set $\,\displaystyle{\color{red}{e^{2x} \frac{1-x}{1+x}}=t\Rightarrow \color{blue}{e^{2x}\frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2}dx}=-\frac12 dt}\,$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

The integral is $$\int_0^x\frac{x^2}{e^{2 x} (1-x)^2+e^{-2 x} (1+x)^2}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{8} \left(\pi +4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{(x-1) e^{2x}}{x+1}\right)\right)$$ as can be verified by direct differentiation.

You can first tackle the $e^{2x}$ part by substitution. The rest should be a trivial matter.

Comment: How did you do this?